# How to run part of a stream without having to execute the whole stream?

Tags: spss-modeler

I use the select node to filter out some of the entries in the dataset, and then run a model.

[image: ss]

I want to save time and not go through all the rows again when I rerun the model. I tried the `Run from here` option, but the execution goes through all the rows again. Also tried the sequal pushback purple button, but to no effort.

Is it possible to only go through the selected rows when running a model, without having to export the newly filtered database?

Answer (score 0):

If this makes any sense to you, I guess it might work:

> Once you have specified the required options for streams and 
>   connected the required nodes, you can run the stream by running 
>   the data through nodes in the stream. Run part of a data stream by 
>   right-clicking any non-terminal node and clicking Run From Here on 
>   the pop-up menu. Doing so causes only those operations after the 
>   selected node to be performed.

Comment: I wrote in the question that I tried this method, and it didn't work because the execution still went through all the rows of database

Comment: You mentioned rows in plural, but in the explanation above it only mentions one, which led me to assume you might have been doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a snapshot of your data?

Do you use more than one column as a target in your time series?

You can change the selection and just click somewhere behind the nugget and use run from here maybe?

What's the error message or does it just rerun the model?